# Copying Data from multiple sheets into a summary sheet within 1 workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and I am having trouble finding out how to create a macro that copies data from each sheet in a workbook and pastes the values into a summary sheet in the same workbook, appending the data below for each successive sheet.

I think my main problem is that the data to be copied does not start in A1.  There are loads of answers where data does start in the first column but I can’t adapt it for data that doesn’t.

The data is in the same location and is the same size in each sheet, so I guess I can Dim a range for each and that I can probably manage.

I need to roll it out to multiple workbooks that have different numbers of sheets in each.  Each sheet in each workbook is named in a generic sheet1, sheet2 etc way throughout.

I do have other sheets in the data that I won’t want copied but I have a piece of code that works by exception so as long as it loops through all sheets named generically that shouldn’t cause too much of a problem.

I’m really sorry if this has already been asked.  I’ve been trying to search for a solution for weeks and have luckily learnt quite a few other useful bits along the way but I still can’t find a solution.

At the moment I am using this as a basis but obviously it’s very manual and I just can’t work out how to make it adaptable and not so clunky.

I will ultimately put in a loop but it’s just the basics of how to address the data that I am having the biggest problem with.

Thanks for reading!

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("AD9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MASTER_QI_SUMMARY").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("AD9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MASTER_QI_SUMMARY").Select
Range("A288").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("AD9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MASTER_QI_SUMMARY").Select
Range("A574").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("AD9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MASTER_QI_SUMMARY").Select
Range("A860").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.

```
Dim wsX As Worksheet, wsS As Worksheet
Dim strSheetsToExclude As String, strArr() As String

Set wsS = Worksheets("MASTER_QI_SUMMARY")

strSheetsToExclude = "Sheet4,Sheet5"

strArr = Split(strSheetsToExclude, ",")
For Each wsX In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not wsX Is wsS _
    And UBound(Filter(strArr, wsX.Name)) = -1 Then
        wsX.Range("AD9").CurrentRegion.Copy
        If IsEmpty(wsS.Range("A2")) Then
            wsS.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            wsS.Range("A" & wsS.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Just add all sheets to be excluded to the comma separated string and may be change the range for pasting.

Comment: Thank you so much @tk78, absolutely perfect for purpose and so easy to adapt.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help you : you can concatenate strings.
Meaning `Range("A" & 2+i*286)`is a valid range for VBA. As well, `Sheets("Sheet" & i)`is a well-defined sheet.
If you loop on `i`, it should do what you want.
I would also advise you to search for posts adressing the use of `Select` and `Copy` if you feel the execution of the macro is too slow.

Comment: Thanks @BluK, this actually gives me loads of options for the future and has helped me view the issue from another perspective.